# SELECT LEFT JOIN with LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem putting a limit on the number of rows from my `Jokes` table.

This is my query working, getting all rows:

```
SELECT Jokes.ID, Categories.CategoryName, Jokes.CategoryID, Jokes.JokeText 
FROM Jokes 
LEFT JOIN Categories 
ON Jokes.CategoryID = Categories.ID 
ORDER BY Jokes.ID DESC
```

Would it be something like?

```
SELECT Jokes.ID, Categories.CategoryName, Jokes.CategoryID, Jokes.JokeText 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM Jokes ORDER BY ID DESC Limit 0,40) 
AS a 
LEFT JOIN Categories 
AS b 
ON a.CategoryID = b.ID
```

Comment: Describe the original task

Comment: limit works for entire query and its to limit the number of rows being returned. In join it will first join and then the returned data will be limited. You can not limit data in one table while joining.

Comment: The task is to create a pagination in php, I found an example that i find quite good. But I cant get the Limit to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not using

```
SELECT Jokes.ID, Categories.CategoryName, Jokes.CategoryID, Jokes.JokeText 
FROM Jokes 
LEFT JOIN Categories 
ON Jokes.CategoryID = Categories.ID 
ORDER BY Jokes.ID DESC
Limit 0,40
```

Comment: I tried this before I'm 100% sure. But now it works. Must have been a typo or something. Big thanks.